# php's escapeshellarg not working with exec (string not encapsulated in quotes)

Tags: php, shell, escaping, exec

I have a simple, two line script :

```
<?
        $str = '"<!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body><h1>FOOO</h1></body></html>"';
        exec('phantomjs '.escapeshellarg(dirname(__FILE__).'/render.js ').''.escapeshellarg($str));
?>
```

when running this from the console, I get :

`Can't open '/Users/me/render.js <!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body><h1>FOOO</h1></body></html>'`

so the string is not encapsulated in quotes as it should be. Anything wrong I'm doing here ?
System is OSX 10.7, php 5.3.6 .

Comment: Do you need the ' and the " ? I thought escapeshellarg put the single quotes around the string anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try this on OS X 10.7, same php version, I get the strings wrapped in single quotes as expected. However the output may not be what you would expect. I would echo out the command you pass to exec first and try to copy paste that command into a terminal to see if it works. You would see the issue better that way. Here's what I did based on your code:

```
$str = '"<!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body><h1>FOOO</h1></body></html>"';
$command = 'phantomjs '.escapeshellarg(dirname(__FILE__).'/render.js ').
           ''.escapeshellarg($str);
echo "$command\n";
```

I got this:

```
phantomjs '/Users/me/render.js ''"<!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body><h1>FOOO</h1></body></html>"'
```

If it's correct and still doesn't work you should check your paths and make sure the files are where the script thinks they are.

Comment: When using your solution it works, even though the only difference is assigning command as a variable.

Comment: Heh. Thankfully the solution was an easy one. Glad I was able to help some.

Answer (score 0):

The final working command :

```
$str = '"<!DOCTYPE><html><head></head><body><h1>FOOO</h1></body></html>"';
$command = 'phantomjs '.dirname(__FILE__).'/render.js '.$str;

exec($command);
```